# Для чего нужен CorrelationManager.ActivityId?

Tags: c#, логирование

Собственно, просмотрел примеры логгера и он пишет дополнительно поле ActivityId, какие сферы применения System.Diagnostics.Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId?

Answer (score 1):

Идентификатор активности может быть полезен, когда у вас есть процессы, которые охватывают несколько классов в многопользовательском приложении, так как с помощью этого идентификтора, вы например можете выполнить группировку.

Comment: "охватывают несколько классов" это как? Когда несколько обьектов дергают какой-то уже созданный, что ли? Группировку чего?

Comment: Перечитайте еще раз то что я написал. Группировку логов конечно же.

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите лог любой службы WCF - там хорошо видно, зачем все эти ActivityId и прочие инструменты нужны.